# (DONE) Request to reopen: How do I convince my employer to match the salary of my new job offer?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How do I convince my employer to match the salary of my new job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123142/how-do-i-convince-my-employer-to-match-the-salary-of-my-new-job-offer)

Salary negotiations are absolutely on topic and not "too broad"

3 reopen votes as of this posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this question has been reopened as well!